# VBA Erro ao exibir dados de um Worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Ando a experimentar VBA e consegui fazer adicionar dados a uma BD na **folha 2**.

E agora tentei fazer para mostrar os dados na **folha 1** onde escolho o **ID** e ele mostra os dados lá inseridos, mas está-me a dar um erro.

```
Sub Busca()
Dim valor As Integer

 valor = InputBox("Numero:", "buscar")

 Range("C24") = valor

 Range("C28") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(valor, Sheets(2).Range("A:B"), 2, False)

 End Sub
```

O erro que tenho é

> **Run time error 1004**
>   Não é possivel obter a propiedade VLookup da classe WorksheetFunction

Esta função já funcionou antes, mas agora dá me erro e não entendo o porquê.

Answer (score 0):

A função Vlookup não está encontrando valor, por isso o erro ocorre.
Há algumas maneiras de lidar com o erro, pois se utilizar a função na planilha o erro #N/A irá aparecer.

```
Sub Busca()
Dim valor As Long

 valor = InputBox("Numero:", "buscar")

 Sheets(1).Range("C24") = valor

 NumCel = Application.VLookup(valor, Sheets(2).Range("A:B"), 2, False)

If IsError (NumCel) Then
    Sheets(1).Range("C28") = xlErrNA
Else
    Sheets(1).Range("C28") = NumCel
End If

End Sub
```